# What does ellipsize mean in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I've added an `EditText` to my layout, and added a hint, and made it centered horizontally.

When running the application, the hint was invisible. I found that I should make `ellipsize` value of the `TextView` to be `start`:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/number1EditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="start"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:hint="@string/hint1" />
```

In Android documentation, I read:

> If set, causes words that are longer than the view is wide to be
>   ellipsized instead of broken in the middle.

The problem is that `ellipsize` is not found in the dictionary. Can anybody explain to me what benefits we can gain by `ellipsize` attribute? And what is the difference between `start`, `end`, `middle`?

Comment: kindly refer my updated answer.

Comment: btw: the actual word "ellipsized" is made-up. It's called "verbing a noun" and is a common way to form computer jargon. The noun is "ellipse" which I assume you know, and it's made into a verb by adding the "-ize" ending which means "to make into", so you can infer that to "ellipsize" is "to add an ellipse to something".

Comment: Old spelling mistake, never corrected. The term should actually be "ellipsis". Ellipse is a curve on a plane surrounding two focal points such that a straight line drawn from one of the focal points to any point on the curve. Ellipsis are the three dots.

Comment: Documentation of ellipseSize has missing description, still.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield I believe back-forming the noun “_ellipsis_” to the verb “_to ellipse_” is much more reasonable than “_to ellipsize_.”

Answer (score 475, accepted):

You can find documentation [**here**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize).

Based on your requirement you can try according option.

to **ellipsize**, a neologism, means to shorten text using an [ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis), i.e. three dots `...` or more commonly ligature `…`, to stand in for the omitted bits.

Say original value pf text view is **aaabbbccc** and its fitting inside the view

`start`'s output will be : **...bccc**

`end`'s output will be : **aaab...**

`middle`'s output will be : **aa...cc**

`marquee`'s output will be : **aaabbbccc** auto sliding from right to left

Comment: Thanks. But I've already read that. It uses the word "ellipsized" where I'm searching about its meaning. The word can't be used in its definition!! Any further explanation please?

Answer (score 85):

In my experience, Ellipsis works only if the below two attributes are set.

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
```

for the width of `TextView`, `wrap_content` or `match_parent` should both be good.

Comment: Actually `android:singleLine` was deprecated since API level 3, so instead use `android:maxLines`.  
Please note:  
> if both singleLine and inputType are supplied, the inputType flags will override the value of singleLine.  
Check out the docs at [R.attr.html#singleLine](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#singleLine)

Comment: @AlbertoGaona
I've noticed that it doesn't work if android:ellipsize="start" and           android:maxLines="2" (or more). I haven't seen any dots at the start although the text was too long.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It worked for me. `maxLines="1"` without `singleLine="true"` didnt work for me.

Answer (score 19):

`android:ellipsize` added in API Level 1. An `ellipsis` is three periods in a row. (...) .

In your .xml

```
 <TextView
       ....
       android:text="Hi I am Amiyo, you can see how to ellipse works."
       android:ellipsize = "end" />
```

At this point, the ellipsis will not display yet as a `TextView` is set to automatically expand on default when new text is entered. You will need to limit `TextView` in some way. Do this, you can use either add to your `TextView` a `scrollHorizontally`, `minLines`, or `maxLines` to have the ellipsis display.

To make the ellipse:

```
    at the end: this is how it would.   
    use: android:ellipsize = "end"
```

And

```
 in the middle:
 use: android:ellipsize = "middle"
```

And

```
 at the start:
 use: android:ellipsize = "start"
```

And

```
 to have no ellipse
 use: android:ellipsize = "none"
```

Note Please :

```
Do not use android:singeLine = "true", it is deprecated.
android:maxLines = "1" will not display the three dots (...)
android:lines = "1" will not display the three dots (...)
```

For more details you can visit [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3Aellipsize)

Answer (score 10):

An [ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis) is three periods in a row...

The TextView will use an ellipsis when it cannot expand to show all of its text. The attribute `ellipsized` sets the position of the three dots if it is necessary.

Answer (score 5):

Text:

```
 This is my first android application and
 I am trying to make a funny game,
 It seems android is really very easy to play.
```

Suppose above is your text and if you are using `ellipsize`'s `start` attribute it will seen like this

```
This is my first android application and
...t seems android is really very easy to play.
```

with `end` attribute

```
 This is my first android application and
 I am trying to make a funny game,...
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example on how `ellipsize` works without using deprecated `android:singleLine="true"` in a `ConstraintLayout`:

```
<TextView
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textSize="13sp"
   android:ellipsize="end"
   android:maxLines="2"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   tools:text="long long long long long long text text text" />
```

remember if you have a text that is supposed to be in a single line, then change the `maxLines` to 1.

Comment: Thank you this solution fixed my problem.  The key is `android:layout_width="0dp"` instead of `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`.  Note this is applicable because I'm using a `ConstraintLayout`.  Also discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48149405/2848676

Answer (score 1):

Note: your text must be larger than the container box for the following to marquee:

```
 android:ellipsize="marquee"
```

Answer (score 1):

Set this property to `EditText`. `Ellipsize` is working with disable `EditText`

```
android:lines="1"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
android:editable="false"
```

or `setKeyListener(null);`

Comment: set above mentioned all property and setKeyListener(null) except editable property.

Answer (score 0):

Use ellipsize when you have fixed width, then it will automatically truncate the text & show the ellipsis at end,

it Won't work if you set layout_width as wrap_content & match_parent.

```
android:width="40dp"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is already mentioned above if there is no enough space for text (due to the size of the layout or set limitation) ellpsize will add ... dots to it.

Here an example:
Top: with ellipsize (here it is set to 'end'
Bottom: without
[image]