# How to make a TextView with multiple lines and without line adjustment?

Tags: android, widget, textview, line, homescreen

In a homescreen widget I have a TextViews that behaves the following way.
If the text content of the TextView has two lines, both of them wider than the screen, it displays something like this:
Line1 line1 line1 line1
line1 line1
Line2 line2 line2 line2
line2 line2

I want it to display its content in this way:
Line1 line1 line1 li...
Line2 line2 line2 li...

Say, I want the TextView to not have line adjustment. If a line does not fit in the screen, I don't want the TextView to display the whole line.

Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does ellipsize mean in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313996/what-does-ellipsize-mean-in-android)