# How to limit the number of lines of TextView's text in Android?

Tags: android

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="3" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="bottom|center"
    android:maxLines="10"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I set a TextView and a seekbar, then set the listener of seekbar to append a line of text into the textview each time the value changes, as the textview get more and more text, the app totally slow down, I try to use things like maxlines or ellipsize to limit, to truncate the text, but seems not working.

Are there any build in things I can use?

here is the java code:

```
this.seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            info.append("\n" + "Stop" + "Current: " + seekBar.getProgress());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            info.append("\n" + "Start" + "Current: " + seekBar.getProgress());
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            info.append("\n" + "Changing" + "Current: " + seekBar.getProgress());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Maybe your string is too length. Try to set the length of the string it may be help and the advantage is it takes less times for loading limited length.

Comment: thank you, You mean it's too long? Yes I agree, and I want to find android build in thing to limit it.

Comment: Too long means length is big.The normal way to set max lines is  android:maxLines="10". That is you are using. If it won't work then try to set the limit of string. I'm just give comment for you it's not a perfect solution. Thjanks.

Comment: Why not check the length of the text in the seekbar listener and, if it is already too long, then just don't append the text?

Comment: @Amsheer `android:maxLines` just constrains how big the box is in the display, not how long the string is that it contains.  For an `EditText`, `android:maxLength` constrains the length of the text.  But since s/he is using a `TextView` and not an `EditText`, I think s/he will need to constrain the length programmatically in the seekbar listener.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the fact that you are using weight "1" collides with the fixed size you want to have. I would suggest to try using "wrap_content" as height value.

Hope it would solve you problem.

**Edit:**

Follow this link and try implementing the solution provided by this guy :D
Replace your textview with the one in the discussion.

[android ellipsize multiline textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160619/android-ellipsize-multiline-textview)

This seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Can you append the whole xml?

Comment: Ok, I put them on now

Comment: Seems the weight_sum is not needed. Have you tried to do it programmatically?

Comment: Unfortunately seems to be a bug and you are not able to limit the number. Why not trying using the solution provided by this guy? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160619/android-ellipsize-multiline-textview. You can use his class. The community is confirming the code as a working solution. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
    final int maxLength = 50;
    String mLongText = "I am very long sentence, but allowed maximum length is 50, trim me if I am more than 50chars";
    if(mLongText!="" && mLongText.length() > maxLength)
    {
        mLongText = mLongText.substring(0, maxLength);
    }
    mTextView.setText(mLongText);
```

**EDIT:**

**You can set maximum number of lines by** [`mTextView.setMaxLines(10);`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setMaxLines%28int%29). This will show a max of **10** lines. In xml `android:maxLines="10"`

You have used `android:ellipsize="end"` which means that `...` will appended at the end.

EX: `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` will be displayed as `ABCDEFGHIJ...`

`android:ellipsize="start"` will be displayed as `...QRSTUVWXYZ`

[Refer this to get more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13314069/1008278)

Comment: how about I want the limit the line...not the length?

Comment: I want the text in the textview just about 10 lines, and the previous lines would be trunk out.

Answer (score 0):

This example cut your text for 3 lines max

```
final TextView title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
title.setText("A really long text");
ViewTreeObserver vto = title.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        ViewTreeObserver obs = title.getViewTreeObserver();
        obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        if(title.getLineCount() > 3){
            Log.d("","Line["+title.getLineCount()+"]"+title.getText());
            int lineEndIndex = title.getLayout().getLineEnd(2);
            String text = title.getText().subSequence(0, lineEndIndex-3)+"...";
            title.setText(text);
            Log.d("","NewText:"+text);
        }

    }
});
```