# Avoid TextView resizing if text is too long

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a TextView that when it has a long text, it resizes to make the text fit inside, breaking the UI.

Is there a way to use a XML attribute to make the TextView not resizable?

I was thinking about using the TextView inside a ScrollView, is there other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, set specific width to textview (It will display textview without scroll)

```
android:layout_width=""
```

If you want to show scroll, add scrollview with specific size and inside scroll layout, add textview like

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:fillViewport="false">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</ScrollView>
```

100dp is dummy size here.

Comment: You are faster than me. +1 for the same answer

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
<TextView
  android:elipsize="marquee"

</TextView>
```

check out this Answer for more options : 
[Elipsize Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313996/what-does-ellipsize-mean-in-android)

this will slide the textView

Comment: and what can i make if i dont wnat ther ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="100dp" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:singleLine="false" 
android:singleLine="false" 
android:text="Long multiline text"/>
```