# TextView make sure text at end will be present

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:ellipsize="middle"
    android:maxLines="2"
    />
```

Notice `maxLines="2"`. now i always want that the 2nd line will be a String that represents the *date*.

for example (very simplified, i'm actually using `SpannableStringBuilder`):

```
 String s = "this string is longer than 1 line"
 s += "\n" + "Today, January, 2038"
```

Now i want to make sure that the date will be present alone at the second row and the `TextView` rep will be something like:

*"this string is longer than...*

*Today, January, 2038"*

is it possible?

Comment: I dont see anything wrong in this, It works well for me as you require

Comment: I know right?? So why it's not working for me? /:

Comment: Even if you dont add ellipsize attribute it should work imo. :s

Comment: No..then the original text will "catch" both of the lines

Comment: :o what does elipsize got to do with this.. it is just a line break.. have a look at this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313996/what-does-ellipsize-mean-in-android

Comment: Have a look at the link you have sent me and check the middle param...

Comment: Quoting from dev site.android:ellipsize

If set, causes words that are longer than the view is wide to be ellipsized instead of broken in the middle. You will often also want to set scrollHorizontally or singleLine as well so that the text as a whole is also constrained to a single line instead of still allowed to be broken onto multiple lines.

Answer (score -1):

First you can try to remove the attribute `android:ellipsize="end"` and see what happens. Otherwise, I suggest you to have separate `TextView` for the date. It is best practice to separate those, it will allow you to give different style to each `TextView` later on.

Comment: well i should left my `p.s` comment that say that i know i can use 2 `TextView` but not looking for this kind of solution. by the way don't sure it's best practice and for sure it will complicate my ViewGroup more than is should. the `Style` : this is why i use SpannableStringBuilder. thanks for your answer

Comment: according to my understanding, the way TextView work is that it fits the text according to the boundaries of its height and width. If the width is too short to display the text is one line, it will overflow to another line.  `android:maxLines` attribute only tells it to limit the overflowing lines to X. you can then use  `android:ellipsize` which will "truncate" the text and for instance add "..." in the end, indicating that there's more text. imo, you have no other option, but to use 2 TextViews. And I don't think line breaks, such as, "\n", have any affect on TextViews

Comment: `android:ellipsize="middle"` was supposed to do the trick, but it wont... /-: and of course \n have effect... try it