# ConstraintLayout does not ellipsize long text in TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-constraintlayout

I have a `TextView` to the right of an image. I am trying to place some long text next to the image but this text should automatically end by adding "..." at the end. However, this does not work. I use this layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/file_icon"
    android:layout_width="250px"
    android:layout_height="250px"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/file_title"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="This is a very long title and I hope I have the dots to break it"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/file_type"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/file_icon"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/file_type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Type"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/file_title"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/file_icon" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/file_download"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_download"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/file_title"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
```

The result is this:

[image]

Why does the long text not ellipsize such that "..." appears at the end? I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45983394/android-constraintlayout-ellipsize-end-for-large-text) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40410786/constraintlayout-chains-and-text-ellipsis-image-on-the-right/43414504) post but it does not work for me. Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use **`app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"`** to your **`file_title`** `TextView`

Try this

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/file_icon"
        android:layout_width="250px"
        android:layout_height="250px"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/abc"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/file_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="This is a very long title and I hope I have the dots to break it"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/file_type"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/file_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/file_type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Type"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/file_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/file_title" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/file_download"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/abc"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/file_title" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Excellent! I was trying around so many times, but this finally did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: Perfect Solution

Answer (score 10):

I've often faced the same problem but for a different reason.  Apparently when you use `ellipsize` you have to use `android:layout_width="0dp"` for the TextView.  I've often mistakenly used `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`.  The person who posted the original problem didn't make this mistake, but I'm pointing out that it can be another cause of "ConstraintLayout does not ellipsize long text in TextView".

Comment: This works indeed. It is not a requirement of the TextView and its ellipsize tag, but as the [ConstraintLayout documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/#adjust-the-view-size) points out, if you specify "0dp" the View will "match constraints".