# TextView get "Real number of lines"

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I have the following `TextView`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:text="Large text"
    android:ellipsize="end" />
```

When I calling `textView.getLineCount()` I always get `3`. But I want to get "Real number of lines" which hidden because I'm using `maxLines`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In xml code, add this to TextView:

```
android:inputType = "textMultiLine"
```

Comment: Check this:    https://stackoverflow.com/a/29465887/10890095 .. your text should be longer than view for ellipsize to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`TextView.getLayout()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#getLayout()) to access information about the actual text currently being laid out.

```
TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.textView);
int realLines = tv.getLayout().getLineCount();
```