# How to create contact list layout with image on android

Tags: android, android-layout

Am trying to create a contact `listview`, something similar with WhatsApp contact list but my layout isn't given me what I actually want.

Here is my expected result, please can anyone assist me on how I can achieve this layout design.

```
-----------------------------------------------
|       | NAME                       |        |
| IMAGE | MESSAGE                    | BUTTON |
|       |                            |        |
-----------------------------------------------
```

// My List item layout example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:id="@+id/contactHolder">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/contactImage"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_no_image" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contactName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contactMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/contactName"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:textColor="@color/darkGray"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/contactButton"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_options" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below layout
changes:

- replaced fill_parent with match_parent
- removed the LinearLayout that surrounds the ImageView
- wrapped bot TextViews into a vertical LinearLayout
- Align the ImageButton to the parent end.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/contactHolder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/contactImage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_no_image" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/contactImage"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/contactImage"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contactName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="NAME" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contactMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:textColor="@color/darkGray"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            tools:text="MESSAGE" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/contactButton"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_options" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

UPDATE: using ConstraintLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/contactHolder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:padding="5dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/contactImage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_no_image"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contactName"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/contactImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="NAME" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contactMessage"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:textColor="@color/darkGray"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/contactImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/contactName"
        tools:text="MESSAGE" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/contactButton"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_options"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: The image, name and message is well placed from your example, but the image button is over the text message

Comment: Hi Peter, So, the message is long so that it overlaps with the button ?

Comment: Yes, so can you limit the layout width of `LinearLayout ` or any other way?

Comment: yes you're right you can set the width of the LinearLayout to for exampe `android:layout_width="200dp"` instead of wrap_content

Comment: @Peter you can also consider the [ellipsize attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313996/what-does-ellipsize-mean-in-android) if the text is too much long

Answer (score 0):

In one way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/contactHolder"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorAccent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/contactImage"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/contactImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contactName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:text="NAME"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contactMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/contactName"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:text="MESSAGE"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/contactButton"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/linear_1"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />
```